# Problem with executor service in Eclipse for android app

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es, wallpaper, executor

Basically, i'm developing an OpenGL live wallpaper for android phones. This is my wallpaper service class.

```
public class Wallpaper extends GLWallpaperService {

private class MyEngine extends Engine {

    private GLRenderer glRenderer;
    private GL10 gl;
    private EGL10 egl;
    private EGLContext glc;
    private EGLDisplay glDisplay;
    private EGLSurface glSurface;

    private ExecutorService executor;
    private Runnable drawCommand;

    public void onCreate(final SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);


        executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        drawCommand = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                glRenderer.onDrawFrame(gl);
                egl.eglSwapBuffers(glDisplay, glSurface);
                if (isVisible()
                        && egl.eglGetError() != EGL11.EGL_CONTEXT_LOST) {
                    executor.execute(drawCommand);
                }
            }
        };

    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);

        Runnable surfaceCreatedCommand = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Initialize OpenGL
                egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
                glDisplay = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
                int[] version = new int[2];
                egl.eglInitialize(glDisplay, version);
                int[] configSpec = { EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
                        EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6, EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
                        EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
                EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
                int[] numConfig = new int[1];
                egl.eglChooseConfig(glDisplay, configSpec, configs, 1,
                        numConfig);
                EGLConfig config = configs[0];

                glc = egl.eglCreateContext(glDisplay, config,
                        EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, null);

                glSurface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(glDisplay, config,
                        holder, null);
                egl.eglMakeCurrent(glDisplay, glSurface, glSurface, glc);
                gl = (GL10) (glc.getGL());

                // Initialize Renderer
                glRenderer = new GLRenderer(Wallpaper.this);
                glRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(gl, config);
            }
        };
        executor.execute(surfaceCreatedCommand);

    }


    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(final SurfaceHolder holder) {

        Runnable surfaceDestroyedCommand = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Free OpenGL resources
                egl.eglMakeCurrent(glDisplay, EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE,
                        EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
                egl.eglDestroySurface(glDisplay, glSurface);
                egl.eglDestroyContext(glDisplay, glc);
                egl.eglTerminate(glDisplay);

            }
        };
        executor.execute(surfaceDestroyedCommand);

        super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
    }


    public void onSurfaceChanged(final SurfaceHolder holder,
            final int format, final int width, final int height) {
        super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);

        Runnable surfaceChangedCommand = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                glRenderer.onSurfaceChanged(gl, width, height);
            }
        };
        executor.execute(surfaceChangedCommand);

    }

    public void onDestroy() {

        executor.shutdownNow();

        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public void onVisibilityChanged(final boolean visible) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);

        if (visible) {
            executor.execute(drawCommand);
        }

    }


    public void onOffsetsChanged(final float xOffset, final float yOffset,
            final float xOffsetStep, final float yOffsetStep,
            final int xPixelOffset, final int yPixelOffset) {
        super.onOffsetsChanged(xOffset, yOffset, xOffsetStep, yOffsetStep,
                xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset);

        Runnable offsetsChangedCommand = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (1 / xOffsetStep + 1 != 0f) {
                    glRenderer.setParallax(xOffset - 1f);
                }
            }
        };
        executor.execute(offsetsChangedCommand);

    }

}


public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new MyEngine();
}
```

}

It works perfectly on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S2) and several others, BUT there have been reports saying it doesnt load. The live wallpaper can't be previewed at all, even from the Galaxy S1 model! Since this works on my phone I cant figure out whats wrong with it. I don't have the phones that cant run the program so i cant fix the problem.

---

thx for the reply. but i am using OpenGL ES 1.0, as you can see with the EGL10... imported GL10. ooh but i saw i did import a GL11 (OpenGL 1.1), which might have caused the problem i suppose??

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported by Android 2.2 and later.

The Samsung Galaxy S1 and many other phones currently available are running earlier than 2.2.

I suggest you double check your API levels and consider rolling back to OpenGL ES 1.0 or writing a wrapper to use it for different API levels.

Comment: woops the answer below was actually a reply to this comment. anyway, i found out that the samsung galaxy s1 android version is 2.2. so i dun get why it doesnt load. not sure wat u mean by wrappers though.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `executor.shutdownNow();` from `onDestroy()`.
Some Samsung phones have a tendency to call `onDestroy` too early, which will shut down the thread.